# Oracle: How to incorporate NVL to this FULL Join?

Tags: oracle, join, nvl

How can I use NVL to replace the null values with zeros in the output of this code? I need the zero's so I can perform addition on these two columns

```
horse_wins + jockey_wins
```

At the moment they always sum to null if just one of the values is null. I've read that NVL can help in such situations, but it's difficult to implement.

```
select
race_id,
horse_id,
horse_wins,
jockey_id,
jockey_wins,
horse_wins + jockey_wins
from
proj_entry a
FULL JOIN
tot_h_wins b
ON 
a.horse_id = b.horse
FULL JOIN
tot_j_wins c
ON
a.jockey_id = c.jockey
where 
race_id = 1
and
where
nvl(jockey_wins, 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
race_id,
horse_id,
horse_wins,
jockey_id,
jockey_wins,
NVL(horse_wins, 0) + NVL(jockey_wins, 0) wins
from
proj_entry a
FULL JOIN
tot_h_wins b
ON 
a.horse_id = b.horse
FULL JOIN
tot_j_wins c
ON
a.jockey_id = c.jockey
where 
race_id = 1
```

You don't use the NVL in your `where` clause when you want to change how a value is displayed. `Where` is for filtering returned rows. If you want to change how it's displayed, use it in the `select` clause.